# WAMP phpmyadmin 403 error, Out of nowhere?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I installed WAMP server 2.2.  Everything installed fine.  I accessed phpmyadmin, I was prompted to login, I did and everything worked great, I was able to create a couple of databases and tables for both.

However, only a couple of hours later, out of no where, whenever I click the phpmyadmin, I am getting a 403 access denied message.  I haven't touched any config files, I didn't restart WAMP server, didn't clear cache....So how can it all of a sudden stop working??

note*, I have found the solution to access PHPmyadmin through a couple of other posts, (by changing the phpmyadmin.conf file to say: Allow from all), but now the login page doesn't show up anymore.  When I click phphmyadmin, I am brought straight to the phpmyadmin home page as if I am already logged in.  I went to the config.inc.php file and set: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] equal to false and still nothing.

Any ideas how it can all of a sudden stop working and how to access the Login Screen again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same problem, except changing the `conf` file doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

developdaly,

You may want to add the line

```
Allow from ::1:
```

to the bottom of `phpmyadmin.conf` (right before the last line containing `</Directory>`). It allowed me to access the phpmyadmin page on my Windows 8 machine, but the authentication window still does not come up.